# MVVM Light UI not updating upon loading settings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm experiencing an issue with UI not updating when loading the properties from a Settings file. Beneath the code is shown, I apologize for the Dutch property names, translation is as follows:

Lade: Tray.
Papiergrootte: papersize.
Geselecteerde: selected.
isEersteKeer: isFirstTime.

I have a usercontrol, a printer combobox, to which the viewmodel code (below) is bound.

```
public class PrinterViewModel : ViewModelBase

    {

        private ObservableCollection<Printer> _printers;
        private Printer _geselecteerdePrinter;
        private ObservableCollection<Lade> _lades;
        private ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte> _papiergroottes;
        private Lade _geselecteerdeLade;
        private Papiergrootte _geselecteerdePapiergrootte;
        private bool isEersteKeer;

        public PrinterViewModel()
        {
            isEersteKeer = true;

            _printers = Printer.GetPrinters();

            LoadPrinterSettings();

            isEersteKeer = false;

        }

        public Lade GeselecteerdeLade
        {
            get { return _geselecteerdeLade; }
            set
            {
                _geselecteerdeLade = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GeselecteerdeLade");

                if (!isEersteKeer)
                {
                    SavePrinterSettings();
                }
            }
        }

        public Papiergrootte GeselecteerdePapiergrootte
        {
            get { return _geselecteerdePapiergrootte; }
            set
            {
                _geselecteerdePapiergrootte = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GeselecteerdePapiergrootte");
                if (!isEersteKeer)
                {
                    SavePrinterSettings();
                }

            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Lade> Lades
        {
            get { return _lades; }
            set
            {
                _lades = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Lades");
                if (Lades.Count > 0 && !isEersteKeer)
                {
                    GeselecteerdeLade = Lades[0];
                }
            } 
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte> Papiergroottes
        {
            get { return _papiergroottes; }
            set
            {
                _papiergroottes = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Papiergroottes");

                if (Papiergroottes.Count > 0 && !isEersteKeer)
                {
                    GeselecteerdePapiergrootte = Papiergroottes[0];
                }

            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Printer> Printers
        {
            get { return _printers; }
            set
            {

                _printers = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Printers");
            }
        }

        public Printer GeselecteerdePrinter
        {
            get { return _geselecteerdePrinter; }
            set
            {

                _geselecteerdePrinter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("GeselecteerdePrinter");
                Lades = _geselecteerdePrinter.Lades;
                Papiergroottes = _geselecteerdePrinter.PapierGroottes;

                if (!isEersteKeer)
                {
                    SavePrinterSettings();
                }

            }
        }

        private void SavePrinterSettings()
        {

            if (GeselecteerdePrinter != null && GeselecteerdeLade != null && GeselecteerdePapiergrootte != null)
            {
                Settings.Default.Printer1 = GeselecteerdePrinter;
                Settings.Default.Lade1 = GeselecteerdeLade;
                Settings.Default.Papiergrootte1 = GeselecteerdePapiergrootte;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }

        }

        private void LoadPrinterSettings()
        {
            GeselecteerdePrinter = Settings.Default.Printer1;
            GeselecteerdeLade = Settings.Default.Lade1;
            GeselecteerdePapiergrootte = Settings.Default.Papiergrootte1;
        }
    }
```

And the XAML of the printer combobox:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ControlLib.uPrinterCombo"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ControlLib.uPrinterCombo"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="ControlLib.uPrinterCombo.uPrinterCombo"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"


    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <c:PrinterViewModel x:Key="PrinterViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource PrinterViewModel}"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrinters" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Printers, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Naam" SelectedItem="{Binding GeselecteerdePrinter}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPapierGroottes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Papiergroottes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Naam" SelectedItem="{Binding GeselecteerdePapiergrootte}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPapierLades" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lades, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Naam" SelectedItem="{Binding GeselecteerdeLade}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone trying to help. I am sure the binding is working, it just doesn't work when I read the properties from the Settings.

The Properties change when loading the Settings, the selectedItem is just not updating eventhough the source of the combobox does update according to the Selected Printer loaded from Settings.

Edit: the code where the Collections are initialised:

```
namespace ControlLib.uPrinterCombo
{
public class Printer : ObservableObject
{
    private string _naam;
    private ObservableCollection<Lade> _lades;
    private ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte> _papiergroottes;

    public string Naam
    {
        get { return _naam; }
        set { Set<string>(() => this.Naam, ref _naam, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Lade> Lades
    {
        get { return _lades; }
        set { Set<ObservableCollection<Lade>>(() => this.Lades, ref _lades, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte> PapierGroottes
    {
        get { return _papiergroottes; }
        set { Set<ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte>>(() => this.PapierGroottes, ref _papiergroottes, value); }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Printer> GetPrinters()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Printer> printers = new ObservableCollection<Printer>();


            PrintServer localPrintServer = new PrintServer();
        PrintQueueCollection printQueues = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
        var printerQueues = (from printer in printQueues
                           select printer).ToList();
        foreach (var printerQueue in printerQueues)
        {
            Printer p = new Printer();
            XmlPrinterUtility util = new XmlPrinterUtility(printerQueue);

            ObservableCollection<Lade> lades = new ObservableCollection<Lade>();
            ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte> papiergroottes = new ObservableCollection<Papiergrootte>();

            foreach (var lade in util.GetPrinterInfo(XmlPrinterUtility.PrinterInfo.papierLade))
            {
                lades.Add(new Lade(lade.Key, lade.Value));
            }

            foreach (var papiergrootte in util.GetPrinterInfo(XmlPrinterUtility.PrinterInfo.papierGrootte))
            {
                papiergroottes.Add(new Papiergrootte(papiergrootte.Key, papiergrootte.Value));
            }

            p.Lades = lades;
            p.PapierGroottes = papiergroottes;
            p.Naam = printerQueue.Name;

            printers.Add(p);
        }
        return printers;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to set if (!isEersteKeer)
                {
                    SavePrinterSettings();
                } befor the onproperty changed event ? for example

Comment: @SeeuD1, Thanks for your response! I have tried that but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Does it showed up at any time ? And where did you initialize the Collections like this.ObservableList = new ObservableCollection<Object>(mylist.toList());

Comment: Added the code where the Collection of Printers and their Trays / Papersizes are initialised. The call from PrinterViewModel to GetPrinters gets the Collection.